# Django - Two auth system completely separated in the same project

Tags: django, authentication

I have a project using django. And now the need for having to completely separated auth system(with different tables, authentication back-end, users, user-info etc) comes in scene.

- Is there any way to make django instead of setting request.user, sets `request.myotherappuser`?
- What about the default auth system, can I still use it to authenticate those 'new users' and  also log them in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming from your phrase "authenticate those 'new users' and also log them in" that you have some legacy system from which you wish to authenticate people?

Why not [write a custom authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends) that logs people in against the old backend, and then also creates them a "new" account in `django.contrib.auth`?

You could also create an extension to the user model using Dj1.5 that allows you to reference the "old" table like `request.user.myappotheruser`.

Comment: is there a way of doing that(third paragraph) using Dj1.4.3?

Comment: @PatrickBassut yes: you can use [this library](https://github.com/marinho/django-plus/blob/master/djangoplus/modify_models.py) to add the extra field from your own custom authenticator app to the User table. Remember to make it `OneToOneField(null=True,blank=True)`.

Comment: sorry, didn't understand quite yet. How will I assign request.myappotheruser to the old table? Note that i don't want request.user.something. I was thinking about a middleware. And the reason I don't want request.user.something it's because there's already a middleware that messes with request.user. So right now, it gives me error(since the middleware counts on attributes that it's not there). But if I use request.myotheruser that will work just fine. Is there such a way ?

Comment: well, you can write your own middleware that executes first and sets that attribute on request.

Comment: but if I log the user in, django will automatically sets the request.user variable. And then, if a user is already logged in the other system, i'll overwrite him and not be able to get back. Or maybe, I will. Using a temporary var to hold the old user. No, won't be possible. See, the thing here is that django will (with no middleware in it's way) overwrite the request.user var when the call to django.contrib.auth.login is made.